# Add item to combobox if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create a dropdown menu with the options depending on cell values, but have been getting error messages instead.

I have: A table with "0"s and different text items, i.e. "ABC" or "DEF"
I want: A dropdown list only with the text items, without the zeros

What I have tried so far:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click() 'CommandButton to reset and fill Combobox
    Me.Combobox1.Clear
For Each cell In ["range name"]
    If Range(cell).Value <> 0 THen
    Me.Combobox1.AddItem cell
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

I got the normal "for each"..."additem" command to work, but then I have all the "0"s as items in the dropdown menu.

Comment: why not define the "range name" to exclude the zeroes?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Dim aCell As Range

    Me.Combobox1.Clear

    For Each aCell In ["range name"]
        If aCell.Value <> 0 Then Me.Combobox1.AddItem aCell.Value
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)